# In-app-purchase in ionic android application using cordova-plugin-inapppurchase

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using ionic framework for android application, now I want to integrate in-App-Purchase. So, I have wrote the code as per the [link](https://alexdisler.com/2016/02/29/in-app-purchases-ionic-cordova/). But it gives error for below code in app.js, when I am trying to load the products.

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', []).controller('purchaseCtrl', function($scope,$rootScope,$http,$state,$ionicPlatform, $ionicLoading, $ionicPopup) {

var productIds = ['productId']; // <- Add your product Ids here

var spinner = '<ion-spinner icon="dots" class="spinner-stable"></ion-spinner><br/>';

$ionicLoading.show({ template: spinner + 'Loading Products...' });
$scope.loadProducts = function () {
$ionicLoading.show({ template: spinner + 'Loading Products...' });
   inAppPurchase
   .getProducts(productIds)
   .then(function (products) {
     $ionicLoading.hide();
     $scope.products = products;
   })
   .catch(function (err) {
     $ionicLoading.hide();
     console.log(err);
   });
};

$scope.buy = function (productId) {

$ionicLoading.show({ template: spinner + 'Purchasing...' });
inAppPurchase
  .buy(productId)
  .then(function (data) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    console.log('consuming transactionId: ' + data.transactionId);
    return inAppPurchase.consume(data.type, data.receipt, data.signature);
  })
  .then(function () {
    var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
      title: 'Purchase was successful!',
      template: 'Check your console log for the transaction data'
    });
    console.log('consume done!');
    $ionicLoading.hide();
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
    $ionicLoading.hide();
    console.log(err);
    $ionicPopup.alert({
      title: 'Something went wrong',
      template: 'Check your console log for the error details'
    });
  });
 };
```

});

the error is "inAppPurchase not define". Could anyone please help me.

Comment: Did you inject `inAppPurchase` in your controller ?

Comment: could you please know me how to inject?

Comment: please show me your whole controller

Comment: I was having the exact same issue, but the solution for me was wrapping the inAppPurchase calls inside a `ionicPlatform.ready();`. e.g. `$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {  inAppPurchase.getProducts([])..});`

Answer (score 1):

Actually cordova plugin was not added properly. So, I just remove and add it again. and finally its working :-)